# How do I redirectTo child component with given parameter in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

app.component

```
@RouteConfig([   
        //{ path: "/:userId/...", component: MainComponent, name: "Main", useAsDefault: true },
        //{ path: "/:userId", redirectTo: ["Main", "Home"] },
        { path: "/:userId/...", component: MainComponent, name: "Main", useAsDefault: true },
        { path: "/:userId", redirectTo: ["Main", {userId: 1}, "Home"] },
    ])
    @Component({
        selector: "app-component",
        template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>",
        directives: [
            ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
        ],
        providers: [
            RouteParams
        ]
    })
```

main.component

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: "/home/", component: HomeComponent, name: "Home" },
    { path: "/products/:productId", component: ProductsComponent, name: "Products" },
    { path: "/cv", component: CvComponent, name: "Cv" },
    { path: "/contact", component: ContactComponent, name: "Contact" },
    { path: "/home", redirectTo: ["Home"] },
])

@Component({
    selector: "main-component",
    templateUrl: "js/app/components/main.component/main.component.html",
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ]
})
```

im trying to achieve something like this:

when user enters a link with a number  `localhost:3000/2` it should redirect him to `localhost:3000/2/Home`

```
{ path: "/:userId", redirectTo: ["Main", {userId: 1}, "Home"] }
```

this redirects me to `localhost:3000/1/Home` is there a way to pass userI instead of specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.component

```
@RouteConfig([
        { path: "/:userId/...", component: MainComponent, name: "Main" },
        { path: "/", redirectTo: ["Main", {userId:1}] },

    ])
```

main.component

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: "/home/", component: HomeComponent, name: "Home", useAsDefault: true},
    { path: "/products/:productId", component: ProductsComponent, name: "Products" },
    { path: "/cv", component: CvComponent, name: "Cv" },
    { path: "/contact", component: ContactComponent, name: "Contact" },
])
```

As it turns out i had to add `useAsDefault: true` on child route, so when the app.component redirects to "Main" it knows to which child it can redirect next. Also i changed `{  path: "/", redirectTo: ["Main", {userId:1}] },` for when userId is not present.

Comment: I don't see `name` being a valid property for the `Route` type. Was this removed in more recent versions of Angular?

Comment: You are correct. It is no longer needed. This question was posted while angular was still in beta :)